# TextView not displaying text

Tags: android

I am trying to get text from getText method from database and display the string in the TextView. But I have no idea why it is not working.

Database:

```
 public String getType(String search){

        String type="";

        String searchTypeQuery="SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseData.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ DatabaseData.NAME+ " LIKE '%" +search +"%'";
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(searchTypeQuery,null);
        // looping through all rows
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String objectName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseData.TYPE));
                type=objectName;

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // return the list of records
        return type;
    }
```

Main:

```
if (database.getType("Sample")=="A"){
                textview.setText("Type");
            }
```

I tried this "textview.setText(database.getType("Sample"));" and it worked. But when i try the above code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `database.getType("Sample").equals("A")` as the if-condition. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) is explanation.

Comment: Please flag or comment as a duplicate. This problem is so frequent, no need to answer, really

Answer (score 1):

You have to use equals method when you are comparing Strings. Remember that Strings are objects.

You can read this to know more info about comparing Strings: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html

Comment: Please flag or comment as a duplicate. This problem is so frequent, no need to answer, really